# How do I use the showProgress flag to display progress in BinaryLoader?

Tags: three.js

I'm loading quite large 3d models using BinaryLoader (up to 6MB), and I would like to display progress information.

Using loader.showStatus was already a 1st step (now my app displays "Loading" while the model is loading), but I would like to show which percentage of the model has already been loaded.

Reading the code for BinaryLoader I found the 'showProgress' flag, but if I set it to true, I get multiple errors like this one:

Uncaught Error: InvalidStateError: DOM Exception 11
xhr.onreadystatechange

at line  BinaryLoader.js:99, which corresponds to:

callbackProgress( { total: length, loaded: xhr.responseText.length } );

I also tried configuring loader.onLoadProgress, but I wasn't able to figure out how to do it...

thanks in advance!

Comment: There is a working progress bar in [webgl_loader_scene.html](http://threejs.org/examples/webgl_loader_scene.html).

Comment: thank you! ...it's quite a lot of code just for adding a progress bar. I'll try to see if I can come with something more minimalistic

Comment: @roberto were you able to come up with something more minimal than what they had given?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

3 years later I ran into the same problem as you. Here is my solution:

```
var onLoadComplete= function (geometry) {
    model = new THREE.Mesh(geometry, material);
    scene.add(model);
    //etc
};

var onLoadProgress = function (e) {
    var percentage = Math.round((e.loaded / e.total * 100));
    jQuery('#some-loader-div').html('Loading ' + percentage + '%')
};

loader.load(file_url, onLoadComplete, onLoadProgress);
```

Reference: http://definitelytyped.org/docs/threejs--three/classes/three.jsonloader.html#onloadprogress

Hope this helps someone!